# Can't display the values from my data base with Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-livewire

I'm using a Livewire component, this is my code:

Search.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Recipe;
use App\Models\Vegetable;
use App\Models\VegetablesRecipe;


class Search extends Component
{
    public $query = '';
    public $vegetables;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->resetQuery();
    }

    public function resetQuery()
    {
        $this->vegetables = [];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->query != null) {
            return view('livewire.search', [
                'vegetables' => Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')->get()->toArray()
            ]);
        } else {
            return view('livewire.search', [
                'vegetables' => Vegetable::all()->toArray()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

search.blade.php :

```
<div class="searchcomponent">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <input wire:model="query" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher...">
    
    @if(!empty($query))
        <ul>
            @if(!empty($vegetables))
                <div class="vegetables">

                    @foreach($vegetables as $vegetable)
                        <li><span class="material-icons">lunch_dining</span>{{ $vegetable['name'] }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                
                </div>
            @else
                <li>No result</li>
            @endif
       </ul>
    @endif
</div>
```

My vegetable Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vegetable extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function recipes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'vegetables_recipes', 'vegetable_id', 'recipe_id');
    }

    public function getName($id) {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

My problem is, every time im typing something in my search bar, I just have a No result appearing on my screen even tho i seeded my data base with some vegetables already. Why doesn't it show me for example Carrot when i type it?
Or how can i fill my array vegetables with all the names of my vegetables datatable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `public $vegetables;` will prevent you from passing it to the view.
Remove that. Also remove your mounting logic.

Thus you should have:

```
class Search extends Component
{
    public $query = '';

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->query != null) {
            return view('livewire.search', [
                'vegetables' => Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')->get()->toArray()
            ]);
        } else {
            return view('livewire.search', [
                'vegetables' => Vegetable::all()->toArray()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure you are calling `@livewireScripts` and  `@livewireStyles` or their alternative syntaxes `<livewire:styles />` `<livewire:scripts />` from your main view which uses `<livewire:search />`.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you could also use a public properly and write to it using $this->vegetables like so:

```
class Search extends Component
{
    public $query = '';
    public $vegetables;

    public function render()
    {
            $this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->query . '%')->get()->toArray();
            return view('livewire.search');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But is there a way to put this all out of the render() ?
So in my render i only have the return of the view?

Comment: Yes, you could also make $vegetables public like you are trying to do and it will autopass to the view. And to populate it with your query results, write to `$this->vegetables`. Check out https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties

Comment: Alright thanks ! I'm gonna try this way

Comment: So I tried it that way but i come back to my initial problem, i keep having a "No result" This is my updateQuery function:
`$this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')->get()->toArray();`

Comment: @LilianCarion What you wrote looks fine. Refer to the code I added to my answer. It should work the same way.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, it works when i copy what you sent, but i was wondering if i could even delete the ```$this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->query . '%')->get()->toArray();``` from the render function and put it like in a updateQuery function.
So I tried to do it that way and now mhen i type something it the search input i just have a No result.
Maybe because im not calling my function anywhere ?

Comment: @LilianCarion updateQuery is not a magic properly within livewire. You might be looking for updatingQuery or updatedQuery https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks You might also be interested in hydrate

Comment: This explains the lifecycle of livewire pretty well: https://morioh.com/p/df597223204b

Answer (score 1):

This is because on the mount you are resetting the vegetable array to an empty array.

Refer to this fiddle for more details:

https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/f51e212a-dab3-4325-b6b0-4c6af4c0ab72

Comment: In the code from the link you sent, the search input just displays every value from the array 'vegetables', but doesn't actually filter them right?

Comment: Or at least, how can i fill my array vegetables with all the names of my vegetables datatable, because you wrote the values in an array directly but what if the values come from a database ?

Comment: Yes b/c in fiddle, I didn't have a database instance. i.e why I showed you using array filter. Refer. @kevin-y answer.

Comment: Please provide the main bits of code in the answer as well, this is considered best practice at SO since sometimes links get broken

Comment: @YakovL Thanks for the tip. As I am new in SO, will keep that in mind :)

Comment: You are welcome (well, my comment went exactly from reviews of first answers, so I hope it sounds friendly enough) and thanks for answering; you can always use "edit" button to improve your questions and answers when you see fit (and even suggest edits for others' posts, although such edits shouldn't change "author's intentions")

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can remove the `@if(!empty($query))` and the `@if(!empty($vegetables))` in place of a `@forelse` utilising the `@empty` statement rather than a `@foreach`. E.g.

```
@forelse($vegetables as $vegetable)
    <li><span class="material-icons">lunch_dining</span>{{ $vegetable['name'] }}</li>
@empty
    <li>No result</li>
@endforelse
```

That way, you will still get a list of your vegetables when the search box is empty, and if it's not empty but there's no matching results, you'll get your "No result" message.

Comment: Yeah but I actually wanted the list to be empty if the search input was also empty haha